# Display new page in jquery mobile through button click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, button

I'm using jQuery Mobile and I am trying to display the second page/div when I click on the button. How do you properly use  tag within the button? Would I need to somehow link it in the javascript funcion instead?

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <form>
                <!-- some textboxes -->
                <button onclick="store()" a href="#pagetwo" type="button" id="savebtn">Store data and graph it</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <!--display graph with textbox data -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, store the data
   function store() {
       $.ajax({
       url: "store data url",
       success: function() {
          $("body").pagecontainer("change", $("#pagetwo"), { transition: "slide" });
       } 
       })
   }
2. In the code example above - on success move the page to your second page
3. On your second page you'll have to get the data you saved